# LastInvalidLoginDate returning NULL, or current date if formatted

Tags: users, datetime, login

I'm wanting to show a user's last invalid login date within the control panel. No matter the value in the database, it comes back as NULL, unless I try formatting it as a date, then the current date and time are returned. Any ideas on why? I'm using `{{ user.lastInvalidLoginDate }}`, and pulling other info through `{{ user }}` works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be another (better) way to do this, but here's an example of adding `lastInvalidLoginDate` as a column to the Users element index:

```
\yii\base\Event::on(
    \craft\elements\User::class,
    \craft\elements\User::EVENT_REGISTER_TABLE_ATTRIBUTES,
    function(\craft\events\RegisterElementTableAttributesEvent $e) {
        $e->tableAttributes['lastInvalidLoginDate'] = [
            'label' => "Last Invalid"
        ];
    }
);
\yii\base\Event::on(
    \craft\elements\db\UserQuery::class,
    \craft\elements\db\UserQuery::EVENT_BEFORE_PREPARE,
    function (\yii\base\Event $event) {
        $event->sender->query->select['users.lastInvalidLoginDate'] ='users.lastInvalidLoginDate';
    }
);
```

Hopefully that helps!